# How to get count of word occurrence at specific location in delimited file in Unix

Tags: file, unix, delimited

I have pipe delimited file, I want to check for value 'America' at 5th position (column) of each record. 
America word can appear in any other columns as well, so `grep -o` is not giving correct result.
Any other way to check the occurrence of word at specific location when file is delimited?

Comment: What do you mean by _check for value_? Do you want to count the occurrences? Do you want to test just whether 'America' appears at 5th position in any record? Do you want to print each cell at 5th position where 'America' appears? Do you want to print each record where 'America' appears at 5th position?

Comment: It works. Thank you much

Comment: Armali -- i was just wanted to check the count of records where 'America' appears at 5th positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script like this can do the work

```
awk '$5="America" {print}' filename|wc -l
```

Of course you can do it only with awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=0} $5="America" {i+=1} END {print i}' filename
```

To use different delimiter you can use in `awk` this way:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN {i=0} $5="America" {i+=1} END {print i}' filename
```

Comment: cut -f11 -d '|' filename | grep 'America' | wc -l this works perfectly also